# jQuery dropdown get ordinal of selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

If the first item is selected, I would get back 1 (or 0 if it starts counting from 0). If the second item is selected I would get back 2. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').index());
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dge8nu6n/1/)

if you want to run it after document load .. without change event you can use

```
alert($('select').find('option:selected').index());
```

Answer (score -1):

I know the question asks for jQuery, but here's how to get it with pure Javascript:

HTML:

```
<select id="sel">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var index = document.getElementById('sel').selectedIndex;
```

Comment: This didn't work for me (FireFox 27.01).  But using "prop" did the trick: var selidx = selapp.prop('selectedIndex');

Comment: I don't mind the downvote, but that code I posted actually does get the index of a select box. Perhaps there's some other factor on your page blocking it.

Comment: I didn't don't vote you. But it still didn't work for me even on a simple test page. Maybe it works on other browsers.

Comment: Interesting. I guess I should set up and link a jsfiddle.